# How to get Specific row height in my table in for loop, Finally i need to Add each row height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var max = 0;
var customeheight;
var rowLength = $('.tbl tr').length;

function recordHeight () {
  for (var i = 0; i <= rowLength; i++) {
    customeheight = $(this).height();
    //max+ = max + customeheight;
    alert(customeheight);
  }
}
recordHeight();
```

```css
.tbl, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl {
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.wrapData {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<!-- This is my table , how can i get each row height, and i need to add total records height.-->

<body>
  <table class="tbl">
    <tr>
      <th width="15%">Emp ID</th>
      <th width="15%">Name</th>
      <th width="60%">Role Description</th>
      <th width="10%">Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfs kldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslk fjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvf ksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbf sdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsd
          fkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfs dbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdf
          kjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjd fvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvf slkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfj
          sdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvf jksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfsl
          kfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsd kjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>10000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfbl sdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfb
          dsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvdskfgsdflskdhfksbdfjksvdghcvgvchsdbclksdsdfsdfsdfsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvf
          ksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjks dvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslk
          fjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdv fsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksj dvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvf
          ksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsf ksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfk354d1dfg4f6d5g4
          fdg4dfg465+f gdfg4df6g4sjdvfj sdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjks dvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvf
          sdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdv
          fskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdv
          fksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfj gfdg g6f5d gdf 6g1 6 gf3dg1 gfd3g1d ksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100004</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Add `console.log($(this));` in your for-loop and you will see the issue.

Comment: use forEach or jquery $.each to get specific element row height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following snippet

```js
var max = 0;
var customeheight;
var rowLength = $('.tbl tr').length;

function recordHeight() {
  jQuery('.tbl tr').each(function() {
    customeheight = $(this).height();
    console.log(jQuery(this).height());
    alert(customeheight);
  })
}
recordHeight();
```

```css
.tbl, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl {
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.wrapData {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<!-- This is my table , how can i get each row height, and i need to add total records height.-->

<body>
  <table class="tbl">
    <tr>
      <th width="15%">Emp ID</th>
      <th width="15%">Name</th>
      <th width="60%">Role Description</th>
      <th width="10%">Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfs kldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslk fjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvf ksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbf sdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsd
          fkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfs dbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdf
          kjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjd fvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvf slkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfj
          sdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvf jksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfsl
          kfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsd kjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>10000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfbl sdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfb
          dsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvdskfgsdflskdhfksbdfjksvdghcvgvchsdbclksdsdfsdfsdfsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvf
          ksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjks dvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslk
          fjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdv fsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksj dvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvf
          ksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsf ksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfk354d1dfg4f6d5g4
          fdg4dfg465+f gdfg4df6g4sjdvfj sdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjks dvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvf
          sdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdv
          fskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdv
          fksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfj gfdg g6f5d gdf 6g1 6 gf3dg1 gfd3g1d ksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100004</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

In your `recordHeight` function, you are using `$(this).height()`. In your context, `this` keyword does not point to the rows. However, in this case, `jQuery` passes the rows in `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this by just modifying your code..**

> Use `$('.tbl tr')` instead of `$('.tbl tr').length`.. and change the `recordHeight` function and also set the equal height every `tr` element except the header `tr`.

```js
var max = 0;
var customeheight;
var rowElement = $('.tbl tr');

function recordHeight() {
  for (var i = 0; i < rowElement.length; i++) {
    customeheight = $(rowElement[i]).height();

    // Set equal max height for all tr element
    if (max < customeheight) {
      max = customeheight;
    }

    // Set new custom height for all tr element
    // Note: this will also change the header height as the selector element is $('.tbl tr')
    // $('.tbl tr').not($($(rowElement[0]))) will exclude the first element i.e is header row as per your html
    $('.tbl tr').not($($(rowElement[0]))).height(max);

  }
}
recordHeight();
```

```css
.tbl,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl {
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.wrapData {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<!-- This is my table , how can i get each row height, and i need to add total records height.-->

<body>
  <table class="tbl">
    <tr>
      <th width="15%">Emp ID</th>
      <th width="15%">Name</th>
      <th width="60%">Role Description</th>
      <th width="10%">Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfs kldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslk fjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvf ksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbf sdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsd
          fkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfs dbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdf
          kjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjd fvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvf slkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfj
          sdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvf jksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfsl
          kfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsd kjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>10000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfbl sdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfb
          dsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvdskfgsdflskdhfksbdfjksvdghcvgvchsdbclksdsdfsdfsdfsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvf
          ksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjks dvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslk
          fjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdv fsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksj dvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvf
          ksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsf ksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfk354d1dfg4f6d5g4
          fdg4dfg465+f gdfg4df6g4sjdvfj sdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjks dvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvf
          sdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdv
          fskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdv
          fksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>100002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfj gfdg g6f5d gdf 6g1 6 gf3dg1 gfd3g1d ksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapData">sdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfvsdfdsfsdfkjfbdsfksbfsdbfskldfblsdvfslkfjvsdjvfsjdvfjksdvfksjdvfjsdvfskjdvfksdvfsdkjfvsjdfv</div>
      </td>
      <td>100004</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```